# Using Jboss with maven eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I have create a maven project in eclipse . 
I want to build my maven project using jboss and also debug it while running
Can any one share there code please on hot to use jboss with maven project.

Comment: Neither building your app nor debugging your app has anything to do with JBoss. It's an IDE set up question.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? Kepler comes with everything you need out of the box.

Comment: @CoolBeans  : sir I want to put the jboss pluggin in the pom xml

Comment: @XtremeBiker : sir  i am using Helios . Actually i have run my maven project in tomcat and also debugged it. Now i have to use a application server , so i chose to use Jboss . I saw documentations online but was unable to find helpfull. If anything that could help me  would be of great help.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/02/21/getting-started-with-jboss-tools-jboss-maven-integration-and-weld